# Improve machine learning prediction speed computation

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, r-caret

I have a knn model still computing since 7 days. Is this normal???
My train dataset has 983669 rows and two continuous predictors and one categorical (DV is continuos). Is there a way to improve speed?

My Lenovo "Legion" has intel core i7 (9th generation, 2.6 GHz), 16GB RAM, 2070 Nvidia RTX, 64bit

Parameters are set as

```
cv <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",number = 10,repeats = 5)

hypergrid <- expand.grid(k = seq(2,30, by = 0.8)

knn <- train(DV ~., data = train, method = "knn", trControl = cv, tuneGrid = hypergrid, metric = "RMSE")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Google Colab (colab.research.google.com). There, you can change your runtime to GPU or TPU and improve your model speed.
Also, put repeats=1 for the beginning.